# How can I concatenate two dataframes with multiple conditions based on strings and NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes df1:

```
| MAPA     | BETA      | CHARLIE | DELTA    |
| NaN      |15.0       | NaN     | NaN      |
| 8.0      | NaN       | NaN     | NaN      |
| 19.0     | NaN       | NaN     | NaN      |
| NaN      | NaN       | 18.0    | NaN      |
| NaN      | NaN       | NaN     | 17.0     |
```

and df2:

```
| E        | F        |  G      | 
| None     | 100      |  MAPA   |
| None     | 120      |  BETA   |
| None     | 140      | CHARLIE |
| None     | 160      |  DELTA  |
```

I would like to concatenate my two dataframes (df1 and df2) by adding each row of df2 to the rows of df1 which are not NaN and whose titles (MAPA, BETA,...) in column G of df2 correspond to the titles of df1. We would obtain this:

```
| MAPA     | BETA      | CHARLIE | DELTA    | E        | F        |  G      | 
| NaN      |15.0       | NaN     | NaN      | None     | 120      |  BETA   |
| 8.0      | NaN       | NaN     | NaN      | None     | 100      |  MAPA   |
| 19.0     | NaN       | NaN     | NaN      | None     | 100      |  MAPA   |
| NaN      | NaN       | 18.0    | NaN      | None     | 140      | CHARLIE |
| NaN      | NaN       | NaN     | 17.0     | None     | 160      |  DELTA  |
```

I did this:

```
no_MAPA_nans = df1[~df1['MAPA'].isna()] #to select every rows that are not NaN
rslt_df = df2[df2['G'] == 'MAPA'] # to select the MAPA line
```

But I get a third row instead of a concatener dataframe.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Is there always exactly 1 non-NaN per row in `df1`?

Comment: Nope, my real data may contain several non-NaN per row in df1 !

Answer (score 0):

One option is you have only 1 non-NaN per row in `df1`, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) as key:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.idxmax(axis=1), right_on='G')
```

Output:

```
   MAPA  BETA  CHARLIE  DELTA     E    F        G
0   NaN  15.0      NaN    NaN  None  120     BETA
1   8.0   NaN      NaN    NaN  None  100     MAPA
2  19.0   NaN      NaN    NaN  None  100     MAPA
3   NaN   NaN     18.0    NaN  None  140  CHARLIE
4   NaN   NaN      NaN   17.0  None  160    DELTA
```

If you can have several non-NaN or None:

```
(df1.join(df1.rename_axis(columns='G').stack().reset_index(level=1)['G'])
    .merge(df2, on='G', how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
   MAPA  BETA  CHARLIE  DELTA        G     E      F
0   NaN  15.0      NaN    NaN     BETA  None  120.0
1   8.0   NaN      9.0    NaN     MAPA  None  100.0
2   8.0   NaN      9.0    NaN  CHARLIE  None  140.0
3  19.0   NaN      NaN    NaN     MAPA  None  100.0
4   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
5   NaN   NaN      NaN   17.0    DELTA  None  160.0
```

Modified `df1`:

```
   MAPA  BETA  CHARLIE  DELTA
0   NaN  15.0      NaN    NaN
1   8.0   NaN      9.0    NaN
2  19.0   NaN      NaN    NaN
3   NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN
4   NaN   NaN      NaN   17.0
```

Comment: This is not done on purpose, my real data may contain several non-NaN per row in df1

Comment: @Adrien, what should be done then? Get multiple rows? See my update

Comment: Oh sorry, YES I have only 1 non-NaN per row in df1 !

Comment: Well, you have two options now ;)